# Unable to parse from Jsoup (local) document to array

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse some team states for a class project from a local html document. It seems like I'm able to find the document just find and highlight the elements, but when I go to transfer that data to make a new Team object the code just skips out and doesn't create anything. Code is below, any help would be much appreciated!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class Comparison {
    
    public void loadTeams() throws IOException {
    
        ArrayList<Team> NBA = new ArrayList<Team>(30);
        File localFile = new File("eclipse-workspace\\Capstone Project II\\src\\localTeamData\\Team_stats.html");
        Document nba = Jsoup.parse("localFile");            
        Elements team = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-stat", "Team_Name");
        Elements shooting = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-stat" , "Effective Field Goal");
        Elements turnovers = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-stat" , "Turnover");
        Elements rebounds = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-stat" , "Rebounding");
        Elements freethrows = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-stat" , "Free Throw");

        for (int i = 0; i < team.size(); i++) {
            String name = team.get(i).text();
            double shootingScore = Double.parseDouble(shooting.get(i).text());
            double turnoversScore = Double.parseDouble(turnovers.get(i).text());    
            double reboundsScore = Double.parseDouble(rebounds.get(i).text());  
            double freethrowsScore = Double.parseDouble(freethrows.get(i).text());  
            NBA.add(new Team(name, shootingScore, turnoversScore, reboundsScore, freethrowsScore));
        }
//for testing//
for(int i=0; i<NBA.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(NBA.getClass());
}
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see when printing `NBA.getClass()` in a cycle?

Comment: Place a breakpoint, check that variables values are what you expect of them.

Comment: @iLya Cyclone I expect it to print out each Team created from information gathered from the parsed file. When I place a breakpoint it just skips over those values entirely and doesn't seem to pull anything from the document even though it shows as being imported successfully.

Comment: `getClass` will just output class which obviously is the same in each cycle iteration. you might be mixing it with `toString` method. Still it would output some text like "class Team" and if your program finishes without error and there is no output, I guess your `team.size()` is actually 0. But you need to find it out using breakpoints and debug (or, worse, System.out).

Comment: Also have you placed your Comparison class in any package? "The use of the default package is discouraged"